# How do I get a json-type response from database?

Tags: c#, sql, json

I have an established connection to database

```
public string Respond(string sqlExpression)
{           
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***; 
    User Id=***;Password=***;";
    var kek = new List<List<string>>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var a = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) 
                {
                    a.Add(reader.GetSqlString(i).ToString());
                }
                kek.Add(a); 
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    return kek.ToJSON();
}
```

This is what the query returns:
[image: database table]

What I get from this method, is this:
[image: json file]

Basically, this is a JSON which contains  external "[]", and inside there are a bunch of "[]", where there is field data. Though what I want is to get json-file with field names ("name", "synopsis","details") and data.

How do I do this without generating classes?

Comment: What's wrong with generating classes?

Answer (score 0):

You should be use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer namespace. You must gather a datatable from your database table. After that you can convert to json with that namespace like below;

```
public string ConvertDataTableToJson()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnectionc(connectionString)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end you will get something like this

```
{"records":[
{
"Id": 1,
"Name": "Foo",
"Surname": "Bar"
}
]}
```

Comment: I am not a fan of recommending JavaScriptSerializer...it's slow, it doesn't handle edge cases well, and it isn't the industry standard.  There's plenty of great serializers out there such as Json.Net or Jil.

Comment: @DavidL I didn't test about speed. My problem was smaller for performance testing. If you have a performance comparison about it, it would be great

Comment: Sure thing: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm

Comment: Or http://theburningmonk.com/2014/08/json-serializers-benchmarks-updated-2/ for a more recent and comprehensive comparison across a number of different serializers.  JavaScriptSerializer will consistently be one of the worst and will have one of the smallest feature sets.